# Swift: declare an empty dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I am beginning to learn `swift` by following the iBook-`The Swift Programming Language` on Swift provided by Apple. The book says to create an empty dictionary one should use `[:]` same as while declaring array as `[]`:

I declared an empty array as follows :

```
let emptyArr = [] // or String[]()
```

But on declaring empty dictionary, I get syntax error:

```
let emptyDict = [:]
```

How do I declare an empty dictionary?

Comment: weird, I get no error doing this, I can even ask for the count and the playground gives me 0.

Comment: mine doesnt give any compiler error even from runtime I can get a println of the constants & they just print this in console 
`array :() dictionary :{}`
print statements 
`let arr = [] let dict = [:] println("array :\(arr)") println("dictionary :\(dict)")`

Comment: [Check this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33151885/1634890)

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID105

Answer (score 365, accepted):

```
var emptyDictionary = [String: String]()
```

---

```
var populatedDictionary = ["key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"]
```

---

**Note**: if you're planning to change the contents of the dictionary over time then declare it as a variable (`var`). You *can* declare an empty dictionary as a constant (`let`) but it would be pointless if you have the intention of changing it because constant values can't be changed after initialization.

Comment: You can declare empty array as a constant but it is pointless. If you read the docs, you can see that an array is always declared as ``var`` as I suggested you: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html

Comment: var emptyDict:NSMutableDictionary = [:]

Answer (score 44):

You can't use `[:]` unless type information is available.

You need to provide it explicitly in this case:

```
var dict = Dictionary<String, String>()
```

`var` means it's mutable, so you can add entries to it.
Conversely, if you make it a `let` then you cannot further modify it (`let` means constant).

You can use the `[:]` shorthand notation if the type information can be inferred, for instance

```
var dict = ["key": "value"]

// stuff

dict = [:] // ok, I'm done with it
```

In the last example the dictionary is known to have a type `Dictionary<String, String>` by the first line. Note that you didn't have to specify it explicitly, but it has been inferred.

Comment: Of the many options available in Swift, my favourite syntax for a simple String/String dict is:`var dict: [String: String] = [:]`

Comment: Thank you!. Dictionary<String, String>() fixed my problem, I had actually a dictionary from Enum to MyClass. What do you mean by "type information is available"?

Answer (score 43):

The [Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html) recommends the following way to initialize an empty Dictionary:

```
var emptyDict = [String: String]()
```

I was a little confused when I first came across this question because different answers showed different ways to initialize an empty Dictionary. It turns out that there are actually a lot of ways you can do it, though some are a little redundant or overly verbose given Swift's ability to infer the type.

```
var emptyDict = [String: String]()
var emptyDict = Dictionary<String, String>()
var emptyDict: [String: String] = [:]
var emptyDict: [String: String] = [String: String]()
var emptyDict: [String: String] = Dictionary<String, String>()
var emptyDict: Dictionary = [String: String]()
var emptyDict: Dictionary = Dictionary<String, String>()
var emptyDict: Dictionary<String, String> = [:]
var emptyDict: Dictionary<String, String> = [String: String]()
var emptyDict: Dictionary<String, String> = Dictionary<String, String>()
```

After you have an empty Dictionary you can add a key-value pair like this:

```
emptyDict["some key"] = "some value"
```

If you want to empty your dictionary again, you can do the following:

```
emptyDict = [:]
```

The types are still `<String, String>` because that is how it was initialized.

Comment: If you wanted to initialize an array of an empty dictionary, you'd do it as such:  
    
`var emptyDictArray = [[String: String]()]`  
`var emptyDictArray = [Dictionary<String, String>()]`

Answer (score 19):

Use this will work.

```
var emptyDict = [String: String]()
```

Comment: I prefer this one. Because we can declare an empty array by `var emtpyAry = [String]()`. That make sense.

Answer (score 16):

You can simply declare it like this:

```
var emptyDict:NSMutableDictionary = [:]
```

Answer (score 8):

## Declaring & Initializing Dictionaries  in Swift

#### Dictionary of String

```
var stringDict: [String: String] = [String: String]()
```

OR

```
var stringDict: Dictionary<String, String> = Dictionary<String, String>()
```

#### Dictionary of Int

```
var stringDict: [String: Int] = [String: Int]()
```

OR

```
var stringDict: Dictionary<String, Int> = Dictionary<String, Int>()
```

#### Dictionary of AnyObject

```
var stringDict: [String: AnyObject] = [String: AnyObject]()
```

OR

```
var stringDict: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = Dictionary<String, AnyObject>()
```

#### Dictionary of Array of String

```
var stringDict: [String: [String]] = [String: [String]]()
```

OR

```
var stringDict: Dictionary<String, Array<String>> = Dictionary<String, Array<String>>()
```

#### Array of Dictionaries of String

```
var stringDict: [[String: String]] = [[String: String]]()
```

OR

```
var stringDict: Array<Dictionary<String, String>> = Array<Dictionary<String, String>>()
```

Answer (score 6):

You have to give the dictionary a type

```
// empty dict with Ints as keys and Strings as values
var namesOfIntegers = Dictionary<Int, String>()
```

If the compiler can infer the type, you can use the shorter syntax

```
namesOfIntegers[16] = "sixteen"
// namesOfIntegers now contains 1 key-value pair
namesOfIntegers = [:]
// namesOfIntegers is once again an empty dictionary of type Int, String
```

Answer (score 5):

**Swift:**

```
var myDictionary = Dictionary<String, AnyObject>()
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm playing with this too. It seems strange that you can just declare an empty dictionary and then add a key/value pair to it like so :

```
var emptyDictionary = Dictionary<String, Float>()
var flexDictionary = [:]
emptyDictionary["brian"] = 4.5
flexDictionary["key"] = "value" // ERROR : cannot assign to the result of this expression
```

But you can create a Dictionary that accepts different value types by using the "Any" type like so :

```
var emptyDictionary = Dictionary<String, Any>()
emptyDictionary["brian"] = 4.5
emptyDictionary["mike"] = "hello"
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to explicitly tell the data type or the type can be inferred when you declare anything in Swift.

**Swift 3**

The sample below declare a dictionary with key as a `Int` type and the value as a `String` type.

Method 1: Initializer

```
let dic = Dictionary<Int, String>()
```

Method 2: Shorthand Syntax

```
let dic = [Int:String]()
```

Method 3: Dictionary Literal

```
var dic = [1: "Sample"]
// dic has NOT to be a constant
dic.removeAll()
```

Answer (score 4):

To create an empty dictionary with the `[:] aka the empty dictionary literal`, you actually need to provide the context first as in the type of both the key and the value. The correct way to use the `[:]` to create an empty dictionary is:

```
var dict: [String: Int] = [:]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create a generic dictionary with any type

```
var dictionaryData = [AnyHashable:Any]()
```

Comment: Thanks, finally because this is needed to add a dictionary type later not just string

Answer (score 3):

Swift 4

```
let dicc = NSDictionary()

//MARK: - This is empty dictionary
let dic = ["":""]

//MARK:- This is variable dic means if you want to put variable 
let dic2 = ["":"", "":"", "":""]

//MARK:- Variable example
let dic3 = ["name":"Shakeel Ahmed", "imageurl":"https://abc?abc.abc/etc", "address":"Rawalpindi Pakistan"]

//MARK: - This is 2nd Variable Example dictionary
let dic4 = ["name": variablename, "city": variablecity, "zip": variablezip]

//MARK:- Dictionary String with Any Object
var dic5a = [String: String]()
//MARK:- Put values in dic
var dic5a = ["key1": "value", "key2":"value2", "key3":"value3"]

var dic5b = [String:AnyObject]()
dic5b = ["name": fullname, "imageurl": imgurl, "language": imgurl] as [String : AnyObject]

or
//MARK:- Dictionary String with Any Object
let dic5 = ["name": fullname, "imageurl": imgurl, "language": imgurl] as [String : AnyObject]

//MARK:- More Easy Way
let dic6a = NSDictionary()
let dic6b = NSMutalbeDictionary()
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm usually using

```
var dictionary:[String:String] = [:]
dictionary.removeAll()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare it as nil with the following:

```
var assoc : [String:String]
```

Then nice thing is you've already typeset (notice I used var and not let, think of these as mutable and immutable). Then you can fill it later:

```
assoc = ["key1" : "things", "key2" : "stuff"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
var d1 = Dictionary<Int, Int>()
var d2 = [Int: Int]()
var d3: Dictionary<Int, Int> = [Int : Int]()
var d4: [Int : Int] = [:]
```

Answer (score -2):

var dictList = String:String for dictionary in swift
 var arrSectionTitle = String for array in swift

Answer (score -2):

```
var parking = [Dictionary < String, Double >()]
```

^ this adds a dictionary for a [string:double] input

Answer (score -3):

It is very handy for finding your way

var dict:Dictionary = [:]

Comment: You have to use the key and value types, too.