# Initialize multidimensional array in swift

Tags: swift

My function has following return type: [String: [String: String]]

However I have to initialize it first but how to do this?

```
var results : [String: [String: String]] = ?
```

Comment: `var results: [String: [String: String]] = [:]`

Comment: It's not a multidimensional array at all, it's a dictionary where values are also dictionaries. There's no array here. And to init, just do `var results : [String: [String: String]] = [:]`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift: declare an empty dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24033393/swift-declare-an-empty-dictionary) (see @Suragch's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31462410/2227743))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply use the following syntax :

```
var results = [String: [String: String]]()
```