# How to implement this Python code in Swift?

Tags: python, swift, dictionary

How to implement a hash table inside a hash table? The example is written in Python, I need to write it in Swift.

```
graph["start"] = {} 
graph["start"]["a"] = 6
graph["start"]["b"] = 2
```

Comment: What research is done by far?

Comment: `var graph["start"] = [String : Int]()`
`graph["start"]["a"] = 6`
`graph["start"]["b"] = 2`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift: declare an empty dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24033393/swift-declare-an-empty-dictionary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should do is to properly define type of the `graph`, because unlike `Python` you have to specify types in `Swift` in declaration:

```
var graph: [String: [String: Int]] // Dictionary(hash table) with keys of type String and values of type Dictionary<String, Int>
```

Then you should initialize `graph` with some initial value, because in `Swift` you always explicitly initialize non-nullable variables:

```
graph = [:] // empty dictionary, in Python it's {}
```

Declaration and initialization can be in one line, so you may just do this:

```
var graph: [String: [String: Int]] = [:]
```

Then your code snippet, with little changes:

```
graph["start"] = [:]
graph["start"]?["a"] = 6 // ? can be replaced with ! here, because we know for sure "start" exists
graph["start"]?["b"] = 2 // but for simple tutorial purposes, I chose to use ? here
```

But it would be better if you would define `"start"` value at once:

```
graph["start"] = [
    "a": 6,
    "b": 2
]
```

---

Or even do it for whole `graph`:

```
let graph: [String: [String: Int]] = [
    "start": [
        "a": 6,
        "b": 2
    ]
]
```